# How can I make a for loop in java for the computer to make a winning move in tictactoe?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to figure out how I can implement a for loop to check if the computer can make a winning move on a 3 by 3 tic tac toe, if so then the computer should make that move. The above code should check whether any of the rows match the condition, but I am not sure what I am missing. Could someone please help me out. Thanks.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){

                if(button[i][j].getText().equals(button[i][j+1]) && button[i][j+1].getText().equals("X")) {
                    button[i][j].setText("O");
                }

            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: looks like your code is completely wrong, you will get out of bounds exception because j + 1 is 1...3, but array indexies between 0 and 2. also algoritm looks wrong.

Comment: First of all you will get an [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) on the last iteration, because of `j+1` thing! And it looks like you want to defend against a forced win on next move, and you have to take into account all possible permutations, not just vertical ones! Please elaborate on what you want to achieve exactly.